# best way of dealing with layers of images / views for an iphone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

If i wanted to create a system whereby you could display a little rectangle ON TOP of an app already running, in which I could put any number of things, what would be the best, most apple standard way of doing it?

I'm thinking of something similar to iAdd. basically layers of views I suppose. I know that microsoft has a standard war of coding game menus for example. they're layered - each one has various event handlers for when things start and finish and they're own little update / load / draw methods etc that get called when appropriate. is there something similar for apps?

The most important thing really is just the starting point. what should I be doing in order to create another view over the existing one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All UI elements in iOS inherit from class UIView.  To add one view inside another use `[view addSubview:subview]`

For detailed information about how to use the UIView class, see [View Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503)